# ThisMonth correct use and alternatives if any

Tags: excel, vba, syntax

The below code works when I enter in a month name.  However, I need it to locate the current month's folder avoiding updating the code each month.  My use of ThisMonth depicted works well in another macro but is not working here.  I believe I am incorrectly applying it.  Any insight is appreciated.

```
Sub JoinPathParts()

    Dim pathParts(1 To 5) As String
    Dim path As String

    pathParts(1) = "H:"
    pathParts(2) = "Rejects"
    pathParts(3) = "2017"
    pathParts(4) = "" & ThisMonth & "\"""
    pathParts(5) = "FileName*.xlsx"

    path = Join(pathParts, "\")

    Application.Workbooks.Open (path)
    Call AddAsLastWorksheet


End Sub
```

Comment: Uh, so exactly what is `ThisMonth`? Or did you mean `MonthName(Month(Now))`?

Comment: You can search the other VBA project for something like `ThisMonth =` to see what it is set to

Comment: Your last edit invalidated answers. Please don't do that.

Comment: I need to take PTO and learn how to post in this site.  Not intentional apologies.

Comment: You've accepted an answer, case closed. If you have a new unrelated issue then you need to research about it, not constantly edit your question as you encounter new problems. Again, this last edit has invalidated the answers you received. Don't you notice the disconnect between the question as it stands and the answers you have? This is a Q&A site, meant to be useful for everyone googling for a specific problem - it's not a "please fix my code" site or discussion forum. I've rolled it back again. Note that another edit will likely trigger an auto-flag and a moderator will need to step in.

Comment: FWIW the `Open` method will fail because you have an extraneous backslash in there.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - `Open` won't care about doubled backslashes.  (e.g. `workbooks.Open "L:\\YowE3K\\Test1.xlsm"` works fine.)  It will care about the quotation mark after the "extraneous" backslash, i.e. the one in `"H:\Rejects\2017\April\"\FileName*.xlsx"`.

Comment: @YowE3K gah, good catch! TBH that whole concatenated line is iffy.. should just be `pathParts(4) = ThisMonth`, assuming `ThisMonth` is declared as a `String`. And even if it isn't and it's an implicit `Variant`, it would still be implicitly converted to a `String` by the `Strings.Join` call. That whole `"" &` concatenation hack is useless. And the parentheses around `(path)` should be removed, too; they're forcing the `path` to be evaluated and passed `ByVal`... which is useless. And the explicit `Call` statement is redundant, too.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - LOL - I cringe every time I see someone coding something as `..." & "" & "...`, **and** at all the superfluous brackets I see.  For a few days a couple of months ago, I used to point it out to people, but it's a losing battle.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - One of these days I will have to download [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com).   But I would probably then get confused having it on my personal computer but not being allowed to have it on my work computer.  :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139908/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-yowe3k).

Comment: Appreciate your guy's input.  I'm not a developer at all, but am being asked to write VBA to help with Enterprise projects we have.  Learning as I go, and hope to share what I learn with others in the future.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - Sorry - can't chat - work computer blocks it.  (Which reminds me, I should really start doing some work :( )

Comment: @YowE3K aw.. make you you check it out once you get home then! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ThisMonth` was probably a function or variable your other macro was defining, and the reason it's not working with *this* code is because, well, it's undefined.

Add this at the top of every module:

```
Option Explicit
```

Your code stops compiling, and VBA complains about `ThisMonth` being undefined.

We don't know how `ThisMonth` was implemented in your other macro, but this could possibly be it:

```
pathParts(4) = "" & MonthName(Month(Now)) & "\"""
```

A perhaps more reliable way is to use the `Format` function from the `VBA.Strings` module, to get the formatted month name - as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216654/1188513) shows.

Comment: Yes, I did define it as ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmmm") in my other macro.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, as I see it will notify me if I leave a variable undefined. Thank you, Mat's.

Answer (score 3):

ThisMonth is **NOT** a VB constant.  You need to define it.

Since you write that replacing ThisMonth with the Month Name works, I suggest that near the top of your code, try adding these lines:

```
Dim ThisMonth as String
ThisMonth = Format(Date, "mmm")
```

**EDIT:** In view of @MatsMug 's comment about international awareness, if that is an issue, you could use something like:

```
Dim ThisMonth As String, M As String
M = Application.International(xlMonthCode)
M = M & M & M
ThisMonth = Format(Date, M)
```

Comment: Note: `"mmm"` will be the 3-letter abbreviated name (e.g. "Apr" for "April") - add another "m" to get the full name that `MonthName` would return. Is `Format` locale-sensitive though?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to define it.

Comment: @Eric As Mat'sMug says in his answer - `Option Explicit` - learn to use it - learn to love it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug The output should be in the correct language, but if the language is using a token other than "m" for the Month, I don't believe it will work.  I have added a few lines covering that possibility.

Comment: No I meant, if the folder is "April" and the output is "Avril" on a fr-CA workstation, this could be a nice "but it works on my machine!" bug! ;-)

Comment: Thank you Ron for the input!

Comment: @Mat'sMug Then you would probably need a translator routine when doing the `Open`